# Os.walk() alternatives

Tags: python, os.walk, subdirectory

I'm writing a program that needs to explore all possible subdirectories of a given path topdown.
My problem is that I need to do things before calling recursion and after finish recursion and `os.walk()` doesn't allow this. More precisely the recursion in the directories subtree that I need is:

(Note: is not real Python code, just Python-like code to explain what I need to do)

```
def recursion(path):
    action1()
   for subdir in path:
       recursion(path+subdir)
   action2()
```

while what I can do with `os.walk()` is simply:

```
def recursion(path):
    action1()
    action2()
    for subdir in path:
        recursion(path+subdir)
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.scandir` instead:

```
def recursion(path):
    action1()
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if entry.is_dir():
            recursion(os.path.join(path, entry.name))
    action2()
```

or if you're using Python 3.4 or earlier versions, use the slower `os.listdir` instead:

```
def recursion(path):
    action1()
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, name)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            recursion(full_path)
    action2()
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `glob` and `split()`

```
import glob
path='this/is/your/path'
pathElementList=path.split('/')
for x in range(len(pathElementList)):
    directoryToDoActionIn='/'.join(pathElementList[0:x])
    filesindir=glob.glob(directoryToDoActionIn+'/')
    #do action with files here
```